# How to store data after shutting down server (jpa derby eclipselink)

Tags: java, xml, jpa, eclipselink, derby

The Data of my webapplication is not stored after shutting down the server. I want to use JPA with eclipselink. 
My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="derbyDB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is one of my classes:

```
public class JpaDAO{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "derbyDB")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void save(final JpaDAO j){
        assertNotNull(j);
        em.persist(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does that mean "not stored after shutting down server" ? You mean you shut down the database and then are surprised that data isn't persisted into it? Or you mean that when you restart it the data is no longer there? And this is Derby EMBEDDED?! as in embedded into the application so hence will always be cleared at termination

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also note you are using  "eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables".  This setting tells EclipseLink to drop and then create the tables when it starts up - only use this for development where you don't want data to persist between runs.